# WPF: make labels in different but similar controls have the same width

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TextEntryControl">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock Width="{Binding MaxLabelWidth}">First Label</TextBlock>
         <TextBlock>Label Information</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And another like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GroupTextEntryControl">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC1}" />
        <local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC2}" />
        <local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC3}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I will like to let the  `<TextBlock Width="{Binding MaxLabelWidth}">First Label</TextBlock>`  in all the controls in the  `GroupTextEntryControl`  to be the same width ... the width of the longest label.

I tried defining a dependency property but I have a hard time determining the longest width to bind to all the controls ...

UPDATE: Layour of UserControls

```
<Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource BackgroundVeryVeryLightGrayBrush}" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1">
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Name="LabelColumnDefinition" Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
                <Image Width="15" Margin="2" Source="{Binding ImageName, Converter={x:Static local:NameToImageConverter.Instance}}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  
                   Text="{Binding Label, FallbackValue=Text}"
                   x:Name="Label"
                   FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeRegular}"
                   FontFamily="{StaticResource NunitoRegular}"
                   Padding="2"
                   ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Width="{Binding MaxLabelWidth}"/>

            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
                 ToolTip="{Binding ErrorMessage}" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding ErrorAvailable}"
                 Text="{Binding InputTextValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Foreground="{Binding ErrorAvailable, Converter={local:BooleanToForegroundColorConverter}}"
                 FontFamily="{StaticResource NunitoRegular}"
                 FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeSmall}" />
            <Border  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" >
                <Image Width="15" Margin="2" Source="{Binding ErrorImage, Converter={x:Static local:NameToImageConverter.Instance}}" ToolTip="{Binding ErrorMessage}" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding ErrorAvailable}" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of `MaxLabelWidth` property?

Comment: Have you considered shared size scope? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-share-sizing-properties-between-grids?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Tanveer Badar
The `MaxLabelWidth` property at the moment is only a number ````public int MaxLabelWidth{get; set;} = 150;````

Comment: @Andy 
Yes I have. The problem is that data is being shared only between child elements of a parent. However, I want the data `MaxLabelWidth` data to be shared across different controls ... e.g. in `<local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC1}" />` and `<local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC2}" />`  Or am I not understanding this?

Comment: If they're all children of the same panel then shared size scope could work. If they're not then you'll need logic in a dependency object and I think at least two dependency properties.

Comment: @Andy
That's the direction in which I am exploring right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use Grid and Shared Size:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TextEntryControl"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="TextEntryControl_First"/>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="TextEntryControl_Information"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="{Binding First_Label}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Label_Information}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="GroupTextEntryControl">
    <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC1}" />
        <local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC2}" />
        <local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC3}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Result:
[image]

```cs
    public class GroupText
    {
        public TextItem DC1 { get; } = new TextItem("One", "11111");
        public TextItem DC2 { get; } = new TextItem("Eleven", "222");
        public TextItem DC3 { get; } = new TextItem("Seven", "33333333333");
    }
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. This approach will make the sizes of all `<local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DCx}" />` equal but not the width of the label in each `TextEntryControl`

Comment: @jnce, All columns with the same SharedSizeGroup name will be the same width. I've added a screenshot of the result to my answer.

Comment: @ EldHasp
This is cool ... it is simple and provides almost the (same) result that I desire. I tried to make the  `ColumnDefinition`s to be like this:  `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Label" /> `,   `<ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="LabelInfo" /> ` but this seems to have no effect. I would like the second column to take the whole remain width. Maybe you have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Okay, I just dropped the `SharedSizeGroup` for the second column (LabelInfo) and pingo! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This solution works as I desire. The solution I posted also works well. I will mark this solution as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using dependency properties and attached properties.

In the Code Behind of the `TextEntyControl` I added this

```
public GridLength LabelWidth
        {
            get => (GridLength)GetValue(LabelWidthProperty);
            set => SetValue(LabelWidthProperty, value);
        }
```

and

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LabelWidth", typeof(GridLength), typeof(TextEntyControl), new PropertyMetadata(GridLength.Auto, LabelWidthChangedCallback));
```

and

```
public static void LabelWidthChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                (d as TextEntyControl).LabelColumnDefinition.Width = (GridLength)e.NewValue;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                (d as TextEntyControl).LabelColumnDefinition.Width = GridLength.Auto;
            }
        }
```

I then created an attached property to manage the widths as such:

```
public class TextEntryWidthMatcherProperty 
    {
        public static  readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Value", typeof(bool), typeof(TextEntryWidthMatcherProperty), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnValueChanged));
        public static  bool GetValue(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        public static  void SetValue(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var panel = (sender as Panel);

            SetWidths(panel);

            RoutedEventHandler onLoaded = null;
            onLoaded = (s, ee) =>
            {
                panel.Loaded -= onLoaded;

                SetWidths(panel);

                foreach (var child in panel.Children)
                {
                    if (!(child is TextEntyControl))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    TextBlock label = default;

                    if (child is TextEntyControl)
                    {
                        label = (child as TextEntyControl).Label;
                    }


                    label.SizeChanged += (ss, eee) =>
                {
                    SetWidths(panel);
                };
                }
            };

            panel.Loaded += onLoaded;
        }

        private static void SetWidths(Panel panel)
        {
            var maxSize = 0d;

            foreach (var child in panel.Children)
            {
                if (!(child is TextEntyControl))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                TextBlock label = default;

                if (child is TextEntyControl)
                {
                    label = (child as TextEntyControl).Label;
                }

                maxSize = Math.Max(maxSize, label.RenderSize.Width + label.Margin.Left + label.Margin.Right);
            }

         
            var gridLength = (GridLength)new GridLengthConverter().ConvertFromString(maxSize.ToString());

           
            foreach (var child in panel.Children)
            {
                if (child is TextEntyControl text)
                {
                    text.LabelWidth = gridLength;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I basically get the stack panel children, get the longest width and change the widths of each child to the maximum/longest width available.

I can now do the following and pingo!

```
<UserControl x:Class="GroupTextEntryControl">
    <StackPanel local:TextEntryWidthMatcherProperty.Value="True">
        <local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC1}" />
        <local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC2}" />
        <local:TextEntryControl DataContext="{Binding DC3}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

This can easily be extended to cover other entry types ... int, float, bool etc.

The advantage of this approach is that I can have different controls managed by different ViewModels but all controls have layouts that blend seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the layout of those usercontrols, how are they related?
Because, if you want the widths to be the same, i suspect that the textblock and entry controls are in some table form? In which case you should use a simple Grid instead of separate StackPanels.

Btw, the widths of controls are availabe via the ActualWidth property which you can retrieve after the Loaded event of the usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `StackPanel` at this point because `StackPanel` fills as much space as possible (maximizing its width and height).

```
<UserControl x:Class="TextEntryControl">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <TextBlock Width="{Binding MaxLabelWidth}">First Label</TextBlock>
         <TextBlock>Label Information</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Instead use a `Grid` normaly `Grid` makes the samething as well but you can define 2 columns. First 1 with specified width as `MaxLabelWidth` and second one as `Auto`. Assign the `Grid.Column` properties of the `TextBlock`s too.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding MaxLabelWidth}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">First Label</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">Label Information</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

Note:
Using `StackPanel` insde a  `StackPanel` with undefined `UserControl`, `Width` and `Height` properties might cause this kind of problems.